# How do I a record a video on iPhone with the screen off?

Tags: iphone, ios, video

To save battery life I would like to be able to record video on my iPhone or other iOS devices with the screen off. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, it is possible.

This method works with at least iOS 9.

> - Make sure your iPhone is locked
> - Press the lock key on the top of your iPhone to brighten it, without unlocking it completely
> - Slide the bottom right camera icon half way up, and don’t let go. Keep your finger in this way
> - Slide the camera modes to video, again keeping your finger on the camera slider mode still half way up
> - Tap the big red record button in the bottom middle of the screen; again, keeping your finger still on the camera slider mode still half
>     way up. Don’t worry if it doesn’t show the recording happening.
> - Double press the home button three times,
> - Keep your finger still half way on the slider, until the iPhone automatically turns off its screen. This will take about 10 seconds
>     regardless of what settings you’ve kept in the auto lock feature
>     That’s it. With the screen off, your iPhone is recording a video.
> - To end the recording and save the video, simply unlock the iPhone

Source: https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/277209